# Scala - Merge two lists of tuples by common elements

Tags: scala, list, group-by, scala-collections

How to merge two lists of tuples that *simulates* Chasles' Relation?

**(a, b), (b, c) => (a, c)**

Here is an example:

```
val l1 = List(("Dan", "b"), ("Dan","a"), ("Bart", "c"))
val l2 = List(("a", "1"), ("c", "1"), ("b", "3"), ("a", "2"))
```

Expected result would be:

```
val result = List(("Dan", "3"), ("Dan", "1"), ("Dan", "2"), ("Bart", "1"))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are there sometimes more elements in l1 than l2 as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically want to consider all pairs of one element from the first list and one from the second and keep those where the "b" elements match.

In other words, we want to map over `l1` and, inside that map, map over `l2`, meaning we consider all the pairs of an element from each list, so something like:

```
l1.map(x => l2.map(y => (x,y))
```

That's not quite right, though, since we now have a `List[List[((String, String),(String,String))]]`--we needed to flatmap:

```
l1.flatMap(x => l2.map(y => (x,y)))
```

Now we have to filter to keep just the pairs we want and tidy up:

```
l1.flatMap(x => l2.map(y => (x,y)))
  .filter{ case ((_,y),(b,_)) => y == b }
  .map {case ((x, _),(_,c)) => (x,c) }
```

which gives us

```
List((Dan,3), (Dan,1), (Dan,2), (Bart,1))
```

That was kind of an ugly mess, so and we can tidy it up a bit--let's filter `l2` in our original `flatmap` and build the result there, so we don't have to juggle the tuple of tuples:

```
l1.map{ case (x,y) => 
    l2.filter{ case (b, _) => y == b}
      .map{ case (_, c) => (x, c)} }
```

This is one of those cases where it's easier to read a `for` comprehension:

```
for {
  (x, y) <- l1
  (b, c) <- l2
  if y == b
} yield (x,c)
```

Comment: Nice approach, I had not seen this problem this way. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

For each tuple in `l1` you can filter `l2` to select the tuples with the matching first element:

```
def join[A, B, C](l1: List[(A, B)], l2: List[(B, C)]): List[(A, C)] = {
  for {
    (key, subkey) <- l1
    value <- l2.collect { case (`subkey`, value) => value }
  } yield key -> value  
}
```

You could also convert `l2` into a `Map` beforehand for better selection performance:

```
def join[A, B, C](l1: List[(A, B)], l2: List[(B, C)]): List[(A, C)] = {
  val valuesMap = l2.groupBy(_._1)
  for {
    (key, subkey) <- l1
    (_, value) <- valuesMap.getOrElse(subkey, Nil)
  } yield key -> value  
}
```